# How can I set the Microsoft Teams program so that the incoming videos (from other participants) are always turned off by default?

Tags: windows, video, microsoft-teams

I use Microsoft Teams on Microsoft Windows. How can I set the Microsoft Teams program so that the incoming videos (from other participants) are always turned off by default?

Comment: From [Turn off automatic video in a call in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-automatic-video-in-a-call-in-teams-a32bd419-00a4-4da6-898c-242b745a21c7): "Video is turned on automatically when you join or are called from an unscheduled meeting in a channel. You can't change these video settings, but you can turn off your video once you're in the call if you don't need it."

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks, great info, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Pardon me, but the comment in question tells the answer is "No, Microsoft doesn't let you choose".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting to turn off by default videos for incoming calls is not yet available:

> Video is turned on automatically when you join or are called from an unscheduled meeting in a channel. You can't change these video settings, but you can turn off your video once you're in the call if you don't need it.

**Source:** [Turn off automatic video in a call in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-off-automatic-video-in-a-call-in-teams-a32bd419-00a4-4da6-898c-242b745a21c7)

Comment: We need a link to a bug ticket on MS's product.